# Why "np.random.rand()" function in Python outputs only float values below 1?

Tags: python, numpy, random, floating-point

[image: The example Output is given here]

INPUT:

`>>> np.random.rand(2,3)`

OUTPUT:

`array([[0.81967966, 0.24861747, 0.1324781 ],`
  `[0.10917913, 0.61025551, 0.87901984]])`

Comment: np.random.rand() generates a random number between 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks Sefan. Just found out.

Comment: @MarkRansom I did read the documentation and it is mentioned there that "**Create** an array of the given shape.....". I was unable to understand the meaning of it and thought that the user has the control of the output being given. So, i asked the question here without properly digging into it. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.rand.html#numpy-random-rand)

> Create an array of the given shape and populate it with random samples from a uniform distribution over [0, 1).